# Python validate and validateommand issues with ttk entry widget

Tags: class, python-3.x, tkinter, int

I am trying to restrict numbers being entered into a entry widget, so that it must be 4 integers long, between the values 0000 to 9999, effectivetly a 4 digit pin number. This class works fine, however, there is a slight issue regarding numbers that begin with 0. If the number 0000 was to be entered then it will only take the value 0 not the actual value 0000. Can someonebody please help me point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
class ConstrainedEntry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        vcmd = (self.register(self.on_validate),"%P")
        self.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)

    def disallow(self):
        self.bell()

    def on_validate(self, new_value):
        try:
            if new_value.strip() == "": return True
            value = int(new_value)
            if value < 0 or value > 9999:
                self.disallow()
                return False
        except ValueError:
            self.disallow()
            return False

        return True
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the value to int:

```
value = int(new_value)
```

If your final aim is to check whether the user inputted four digits, you can also use a very simple regular expression:

```
import re

def on_validate(self, new_value):
    m = re.match(r'^(\d{1,4})?$', new_value)
    if m is None:
        self.disallow()
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work applying to the class above, im getting an error "module" object has no attributes "matches"

Comment: @user2207573 Sorry, it was a typo. The name of the function is [`match`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.match)

Comment: I noticed  that just before we looking at the module, however, this change still casuses erros to occur 'File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2474, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
_tkinter.TclError: expected boolean value but got "None"'

Comment: @user2207573 I've just realized you are using "key" as the validation condition, I'll change my answer to reflect that. The error you get is from a `delete` method, not from `on_validate`.

Comment: Yes but implementing the above method removes all function from the 'entry' I take it this is down to the key problem?